# How to test handler message using roboelectric or mockito

Tags: android, android-testing, android-handler

I'm trying to test a piece of code using roboelectric and mockito framework that contains a `handler.sendMessage(msg):`

```
public void emailLogin(){
...
    mHandler.sendMessage(message);
}

Handler mHandler = new Handler(new Callback() {

        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            System.out.println("called");
            return false;
        }
});
```

The handler works perfectly without normal envoirnment,
but if I write a unit test for that method, the handler is 
not triggered.

Is the handler.sendMessage(msg) missing from robolectric?
Or We have to test handler seperately?

I don't want to test the handler it self through a unit test,
what I want to test is my function, that contains the handler.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look into:

```
Robolectric.runUiThreadTasks();
```

I was running into the same problem with Handlers inside the loopj Android Asynchronous Http Client library not getting hit when running tests with using the `RobolectricTestRunner` class, and ended up using similar approach that was mentioned here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robolectric/hbcTw3jLXys